# Angular 2 Support for Joomla & Wordpress

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Expect to know by using angular 2, If we can able to develop Templates,Components,Modules for Joomla and WordPress?

Comment: Yes, of course you can know are to be able! Jokes aside, you're not limited by these content management systems. They can be used to only "manage" the content, how you display it is up to you.

Comment: Here's a good guide: http://doppiaeast.com/article/angular-2-wordpress-theme-setup/